# Filter one Array which is in another array

Tags: arrays, node.js, filter

So I have one array which contains two different arrays:

```
 var _staticRoutingTable = [];

 function StaticRoute(directory, extentions) {
        this.dir = directory;
        this.extentions = extentions;
 }

_staticRoutingTable.push(new StaticRoute(["htmlfolder"], ["./html"]));
_staticRoutingTable.push(new StaticRoute(["somefolder"], ["./html","./txt","./css"]));
```

Lets say I want only get the "dir" Array where the name of the folder is "somefolder".

So I dont want smth like this because...:

```
 return _staticRoutingTable.forEach(function callb(route) {           
       return route.dir.filter(function callb(directory) {directory=="somefolder" })
 });
```

.... I get dir + extention array. How can I only filter one array (in this case "dir").

Comment: So you want the StaticRoute in complete, which has this.dir == 'somefolder' ?

Comment: @baao No, I dont want the StaticRoute in complete, I just want to return one array, which contains a string called "somefolder"(in this example9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stil not sure if I understand your question correctly - but to get an array like `['something']`, you can use find:

```js
var _staticRoutingTable = [];

function StaticRoute(directory, extentions) {
    this.dir = directory;
    this.extentions = extentions;
}

_staticRoutingTable.push(new StaticRoute(["htmlfolder"], ["./html"]));
_staticRoutingTable.push(new StaticRoute(["somefolder"], ["./html","./txt","./css"]));

let foo = _staticRoutingTable.find(function (a) {
    return a.dir.indexOf("somefolder") > -1;
});
if (foo) {
    console.log(foo.dir);    
}
```

Note that this will return the first match only. If there are multiple possible matches you're interested in, you can switch filter for find and work with the resulting array then.

However, as you are searching for 'somefolder' and want to return an array like `['somefolder']`, it would be easier to just do

```
console.log(['somefolder']);
```

...

This works for multiple matches:

```js
    var _staticRoutingTable = [];

    function StaticRoute(directory, extentions) {
        this.dir = directory;
        this.extentions = extentions;
    }

    _staticRoutingTable.push(new StaticRoute(["htmlfolder"], ["./html"]));
    _staticRoutingTable.push(new StaticRoute(["somefolder"], ["./html","./txt","./css"]));

    let foo = _staticRoutingTable.filter(function (a) {
        return a.dir.indexOf("somefolder") > -1;
    });
    foo.forEach(function (v) { console.log(v.dir); });
```

Comment: So this only works, if the array has only one index with the value "somefolder"?

Comment: As I wrote, if there are multiple, replace find with filter @igodie

Comment: Edited the answer @igodie